# How to define the order of a 'composite' finite differences aproximation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, computational-mathematics

If I'm trying to aproximate the solution to a BVP, such as this unidimentional Poisson equation with Dirichlet and Neumann border conditions:

$$\dfrac{d^2u(x)}{dx^2}=\exp\left(-x^2\right),\quad \dfrac{du(0)}{dx}=-1, \quad u(1)=1,\quad 0\leq x \leq 1$$

I'll naturally define:
$$w_i=u(0+ih)$$
With $h$ as the step size. 
$$\dfrac{d^2u(x)}{dx^2}=\dfrac{w_{i+1}-2w_{i}+w_{i-1}}{h^2}+\text{O}\left(h^2\right)=\exp\left(-(ih)^2\right)\tag{1}\label{1}$$

And, in order to take into account the Neumann condition:

$$\dfrac{du(0)}{dx}=\dfrac{w_1-w_0}{h}+\text{O}(h)=-1\tag{2}\label{2}$$

Such that:

$$w_0=w_1+h+\text{O}(h^2)\tag{3}\label{3}$$

This way, the first equation of the system using equation \eqref{1} and \eqref{3}:

$$\dfrac{w_{2}-2w_{1}+w_{0}}{h^2}=\exp(-h^2)=\dfrac{w_{2}-2w_{1}+(w_1+h)}{h^2}\tag{4}\label{4}$$

$$w_{2}-w_{1}=h^2\exp(-h^2)-h\tag{5}\label{5}$$

And the last equation, using the Dirichlet condition:

$$\dfrac{w_{n}-2w_{n-1}+w_{n-2}}{h^2}=\exp(-((n-1)h)^2)\tag{6}\label{6}$$
$$-2w_{n-1}+w_{n-2}=h^2\exp(-((n-1)h)^2)-1\tag{7}\label{7}$$

Therefore, the matrix form of the system:

$$\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0\\ 1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\ 0 & 1 & -2 & 1 & \dots & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & \dots & \dots & 0 & 1 & -2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}w_1\\w_2\\w_3\\ \vdots\\ w_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}h^2\exp(-h^2)-h\\h^2\exp(-(2h)^2)\\h^2\exp(-(3h)^2)\\ \vdots\\ h^2\exp(-((n-1)h)^2)-1\end{bmatrix}$$

So, my question is: What's the **order** of the entire aproximation?

I'm aware that the second derivative it's under an aproximation of second order, but what's the influence of the Forward Difference \eqref{2} aproximation on the overall process? Does it propagate over the system?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Usually yes, a low order boundary condition approximation spoils the whole scheme. You should use the same order everywhere. For Neumann boundaries, ghost points are a good tool for setting this up nicely.

Comment: (Also you mixed up the names Dirichlet and Neumann.)

Comment: Oops, I have already fixed it.
In that case, if I use something like $\dfrac{-3w_{i+1}+4w_i-w_{i-1}}{2h}$ which is second order, the overall aproximation would be of second order?. I'm also interested in the proof of such statement. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the overall approximation becomes second order if you make the BC approximation be second order as well. For BVPs rather than IVPs this is difficult to prove. Typically it is easier to take a detour to finite element methods and then derive an equivalence between your FD method and a FE method. FE methods have more structure available to use to prove such convergence.